# Prolog. Сравнение двух списков

Tags: prolog

Всем привет, начну сразу с задания. Звучит оно так:

> l1, l2 - списки, элементами которых являются атомы. Выяснить, содержит ли список l1 все элементы из списка l2 (только одно вхождение).

Программирую я на Visual Prolog 5.2. Только начинаю изучать этот язык в образовательных целях. Попробовал написать такую программу, но она не совсем верная:

```
domains

il=integer*

predicates

prefix(il,il)

equal(il,il)

clauses

prefix([H|T1],[H|T2]):- !,prefix(T1,T2).

prefix(_,[]).


equal([H|T1],[H|T2]):- !,prefix(T1,T2).

equal([_|T1],L2):- equal(T1,T2).

goal

equal([4,45,5,2,1,4,6,7],[5,2,1,4]).
```

При данном запросе мы получаем **Yes**, но, если, например, два списка будут такими: `[1,2,3,4] [3,2,1,4]`, то получим **No**, что не удовлетворяет условию поставленной задачи. Прошу помочь разобраться со своей ошибкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данной проверке у вас три переменные:

```
equal([_|T1],L2):- equal(T1,T2).
```

T2 - не имеет значение и поэтому присваивается T2 := T1 . У вас всегда всё остановиться на **true**.

Вы пытались сравнить списки , где только сравниваете первые элементы, а нужно искать в других местах.

Чтобы найти сами свои баги, пишите отладку с помощью `write`.

Вот мой пример, где ищу вхождение элемента, а затем удаляю из первого списка.

```
содержит(X,[]) :- ! ,write("содержит([X],[]):X="),writeln(X).
содержит(L,[B|D]) :-
  write("содержит(L,[B|D]):"),
  write("L="),writeln(L),
  write("B="),writeln(B),
  writeln("D="),writeln(D),
  member(B,L),
  writeln("B нашёл"),
  select(B,L,L2),
  writeln("удалил B"),
  содержит(L2,D).
```